Match formula that ignores NULL values
I have a main sheet that looks like this, with many more rows for further IDs:

I am attempting to create a True/False calculated column (called 'Match?') where I can check if the ID, time, and value match to a second sheet:

Essentially, I want a 1 if all 3 columns match, and 0 if they do not. The formula I am using is:
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$11, 0)+MATCH(B2, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$11,0)+MATCH(C2, Sheet2!$C$2:$C$11,0)), 0, 1) 

This only works for the first row, and also does not deal with the NULL values properly. I would like a match with a NULL value to return 0.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Try using the following, NULL is empty:


=IF(C2="NULL",0,IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,(A2=$F$2:$F$12)*(B2=$G$2:$G$12)*(C2=$H$2:$H$12),0)),0,1))


Or,
=IF(C2="",0,IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,(A2=$F$2:$F$12)*(B2=$G$2:$G$12)*(C2=$H$2:$H$12),0)),0,1))


